# (UK) Toilet flush makes a vibrating, grinding sound just at the start of filling

Tags: plumbing, toilet, noise, cistern

I had a bathroom renovation including totally new toilet (using the existing plumbing) with new cistern, pan, etc.

After installation, but not immediately, I started having this vibrating / grinding sound in the pipe after flushing, it happens just as it starts to fill up. When I open the lid, the part with the ball cock seems to visibly vibrate a bit when it makes the noise.

The sound lasts about 3-4 seconds and cistern fills normally so I don't think it's a problem as such but it is quite annoying!

It has only been installed for about a month so not long enough for scale to build up I assume.

I'm curious what could cause this (and if I can investigate/fix it myself without calling the installer back for something as minor as that) especially since it didn't start happening immediately after the installation?

I haven't changed anything else in the plumbing since it was installed.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps some debris from the pipe got knocked loose and is lodged in the valve affecting it.

Comment: @jwh20 is that something I can investigate myself (and how)? Keeping in mind I am a reasonably intelligent person but no particular knowledge of plumbing etc.

Comment: Sounds like valve flutter.  Flush the toilet then adjust the fill valve flow manually by hand to see if the vibration stops/changes.  If it does you can turn off your water and remove the valve and give it clean.  However it would probably be better to just swap it for a new one